# Why the push queue is disabled

Tags: google-app-engine, queue

I defined a custom queue in my module for driving backup jobs

```
- name: backup
  rate: 1/h
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

But for some reason GAE has disabled the queue

[image]

The red exclamation mark has this in the tooltip:

```
The queue has been disabled, and removed from queue.xml/queue.yaml
```

And there is the only information I get from the console so far.

What is the problem with my queue definition?

Comment: This can happen if someone deploy without the correct queue.yaml. You can check admin logs which record all deployment and setting modification

Comment: There's a problem in new console, check it on appengine.google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit `h` in rate is invalid. It should be `1/s` instead